# Can I highlight a word with a right click in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, mouse-click

I mean, I click on a word, it highlights, and the context menu shows up as well.

Comment: So what you want is to have a single right click on a word do what a double click and then a right click on a word does?

Comment: Right-clicking a word in Chrome highlights the word and opens the context menu, at least for me (using OS X Mavericks).